# Select unique rows with many different columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my table:

```
Ref Num   Status    Task Status   Task N
-----------------------------------------
TB011       RET       Null        0  
TB012       RET       Null        0  
TB013       INP       Ready       100  
TB013       INP       Null        0  
TB013       INP       Null        0  
TB014       INP       In Process  100  
TB014       INP       Null        0  
TB014       INP       Null        0  
TB015       INP       Completed   100  
TB015       INP       Ready       200  
TB015       INP       Null        0  
TB016       INP       Ready       100  
TB016       INP       In Process  150  
TB016       INP       Null        0  
TB017       INP       Completed   100  
TB017       INP       In Process  150  
TB017       INP       Ready       199  
TB017       INP       Null        0
```

I need to get unique row of each "Ref Num" where:

- `if Status = RET` there only going to be one row where Task Status will always be null
- `if Status = INP` I need only the first row where Task Status is not Completed

I have add "Task N" row with is a number, maybe it will help

The result should look like that:

```
Ref Num   Status    Task Status   Task N   
------------------------------------------
TB011       RET       Null        0  
TB012       RET       Null        0  
TB013       INP       Ready       100   
TB014       INP       In Process  100    
TB015       INP       Ready       200  
TB016       INP       Ready       100  
TB017       INP       In Process  150
```

! I have many more columns after Ref Num, Status, Task Status, Task N with different data and I also need them.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question with your database.  Also, SQL tables represent unordered sets.  They have no concept of "first".  You need a separate column to define the ordering, typically an id or creation date.

Comment: Please use the `Code`-button to format blocks and don't add `_______` everywhere. That makes it impossible to create your sample data in sql-fiddle or to help you to format it here.

Comment: 'if Status = INP I need only the first row where Task Status is not Completed' sorted by what? Which column determinates what is first what is last?

Comment: Task N is smaller in first task, except 0 with means that there wore nothing

Comment: `first` can be determined (once we have a way to order the data); BUT there are different ways to do this depending on the dbms Oracle & SQL Server (& others) can use `ROW_NUMBER()` but MySQL cannot. PLEASE specify the dbms you use (and version); Do this for every question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont konw DB engine.
But it may look like this:

```
SELECT * (

SELECT `Ref Num`,Status,`Task Status`,`Task N` 
FROM table
WHERE Status = 'RET'

UNION 

SELECT `Ref Num`,Status,`Task Status`,`Task N` 
FROM table
WHERE Status = 'INP' AND
`Task Status` <> 'Completed'
GROUP BY  `Ref Num`,Status
ORDER BY ORDER BY `Ref Num` ASC


) ORDER BY `Ref Num` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the dbms is vital to solution choice, please specify the dbms with your question. This solution will match the expected result for those dbms that support row_number()

```
SELECT
      Ref_Num
    , Status
    , Task_Status
    , Task_N
FROM (
            SELECT
                  Ref_Num
                , Status
                , Task_Status
                , Task_N
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REF_NUM
                                     ORDER BY task_N ASC) AS RN
            FROM table1
            WHERE status = 'RET'
                  OR (status = 'INP'
                  AND task_status <> 'Completed'
                  AND task_n <> 0)
      ) d
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER BY
      Ref_Num
;
```

<kbd>[see this SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1df3a/1)</kbd>